# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Like'. vb net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, vb.net-2010

i selected with dropwdonlist and textbox
from sqlserver to another form in asp vb.net
but give me error 
incorrect syntax near like
script is that

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Len(Session("LibuserID")) = 0 Then
            Response.Redirect("./index.aspx")
        End If
        Dim DBConn As SqlConnection
        Dim DBCommand As SqlDataAdapter 
        Dim DSPageData As New DataSet
        DBConn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;" & _
       "initial catalog=test;Integrated Security=True;")
        If Request.QueryString("Type") = "Search" Then
            lblMessage.Text = "Resultati Poiska:"
            DBCommand = New SqlDataAdapter _
                ("Select LibBookID,BookTitle,Author,Status " _
                 & "from LibBooks where " _
                 & Request.QueryString("ddlSearchField") & "Like '%" _
                 & Replace(Request.QueryString("txtSearchText"), "'", "''") _
                 & "&' order by BookTitle", DBConn)
        ElseIf Request.QueryString("Type") = "Browse" Then
            lblMessage.Text = "kniqi otnosyasiesya k etoy kategorii:"
            DBCommand = New SqlDataAdapter _
                ("select LibBookID,BookTitle,Author,Status " _
                 & "from LibBooks where " _
                 & "LibBookCategoryID = " _
                 & Request.QueryString("LibBookCategoryID") _
                 & "Order By BookTitle", DBConn)
        Else
            Response.Redirect("./menu.aspx")
        End If
        DBCommand.Fill(DSPageData, _
                       "Books")
        dbBooks.DataSource = _
            DSPageData.Tables("Books").DefaultView
        dbBooks.DataBind()

End Sub
```

error is that

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Like'.

```
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Like'.

Source Error: 


Line 33:             Response.Redirect("./menu.aspx")
Line 34:         End If
Line 35:         DBCommand.Fill(DSPageData, _
Line 36:                        "Books")
Line 37:         dbBooks.DataSource = _
```

Comment: This is a sql injection invitation instead of a web application. Use parametrized queries instead of string concatenation. All the more with a web-application where the sql string is built from url-parameters.

Comment: "&" is not a SQL wildcard.

Comment: this script from book greg bucek asp_net and & is from vb_net

Comment: Change the book. Anything that teaches this mess should be dumped ASAP. By the way, probably there is a missing space here: _Request.QueryString("ddlSearchField") & "Like '%"_ If it is just your typo then this question should be closed. If comes from the book, they have not tested their code. Another reason for the dump bin

Comment: yeah may be was not testing this query ,but how can i update in this query  Request.QueryString("ddlSearchField") & "Like '%"   ?????????

Comment: Try to clear your query using space before `LIKE` I think it missed. If possible see the values in query in debug mode

Comment: yes but how can i update like ?can you example ?

Comment: not anybody help for this quession?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a space before your *LIKE* clause.

> & Request.QueryString("ddlSearchField") & " Like '%" _

Comment: Thanks was add & in button click.but i was write to author book "greg buczek" too.why this prob i dont was understand

Answer (score 0):

As someone is saying you should use a parametrized query instead of this.
Probably your problem is that`Request.QueryString("ddlSearchField")` is null or empty, so if you want to change your query into a parametrized you have to rewrite all, if you just want it to work you have to check if values are null or empty.